# Hadoop archive utility alternative for CEPH

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, ceph

I have some HAR files (Hadoop archive files) on my HDFS based storage, which have some archived data that is not frequently used.

Now we have a plan to move to CEPH based storage. So I have 2 questions:

1. Can I somehow use my existing HAR files on CEPH?
2. Does CEPH have some archive utility like HDFS has Hadoop Archive utility?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I have used Hadoop but I can answer following questions:

- *Can I somehow use my existing HAR files on CEPH?*

  Although I am sure there is no official support for HAR in Ceph, I think its still possible since Ceph file system can be used as a drop-in replacement for the Hadoop File System (HDFS).
- *Does CEPH have some archive utility like HDFS has Hadoop Archive utility?*

  Since I use Ceph on daily basis, I have not come across any such archive utility in Ceph similar to HAR. As you know, HAR uses .tar extension. Therefore, what I have been doing is using compressed tarballs. For block devices I store the tarballs as [Ceph RBD (rados block device)](https://docs.ceph.com/en/pacific/rbd/index.html) volumes. And if I am working with Objects, I archive the tarballs as [RGW](https://docs.ceph.com/en/latest/man/8/radosgw/) objects.

In order to help you further I am sharing some useful threads to dig deeper:

- [optimise small files performance: store small files in "superchunks" [feature]](https://github.com/moosefs/moosefs/discussions/370)
- [A practical approach to efficiently store 100 billions small objects in Ceph](https://wiki.softwareheritage.org/wiki/A_practical_approach_to_efficiently_store_100_billions_small_objects_in_Ceph)
- [Storing 20 billions of immutable objects in Ceph, 75% <16KB](https://www.mail-archive.com/ceph-users@ceph.io/msg08811.html)

Comment: thanks for your answer. How do you archive your files on CEPH then? What about small files?

Comment: I use tarballs. Please check my updated answer. I have shared some useful threads. May be helpful for you.

Comment: @pri: Has my answer helped or given some helpful pointers? Please let me know as it is encouraging for newcomers like me on SO to answer questions :)